# "Not enough input arguments" error using add_line()

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to use `add_line()` to organize a link with the 'autorouting' parameter.

Here is my code :

```
add_line(sprintf('%s',diagrammeName), [pos_array_out{pos_out};pos_array_in{pos_in}], 'autorouting','on');
```

where `pos_array_out` is a cell of Output position and `pos_array_in` is a cell of Input position.

And `pos_in` and `pos_out` are indices of cell.

But it returns an error :

```
Not enough input arguments
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

[`add_line()`](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html) has three mandatory arguments when using name-value pairs: `sys`, `out`, and `in`, and optional name-value pairs. Breaking down your input:

```
add_line(sprintf('%s',diagrammeName),...
         [pos_array_out{pos_out};pos_array_in{pos_in}],...
         'autorouting','on'...
         );
```

Directly tells you what the problem is. You have two input variables: 1) `sprintf('%s',diagrammeName)`, 2) `[pos_array_out{pos_out};pos_array_in{pos_in}]`, and the name-value pair (`'autorouting','on'`). So basically you fed it two of the three mandatory parameters, hence you get the error.

I suspect, due to the way you use your variable names, you should do

```
add_line(sprintf('%s',diagrammeName),...
         pos_array_out{pos_out},...
         pos_array_in{pos_in},...
         'autorouting','on'...
         );
```

i.e. split the `out` and `in` variables as suggested in the documentation.

The other type of input `add_line()` accepts is `h = add_line(sys,points)`, in which case you have two positional arguments, like you do here, but cannot use name-value pairs apparently. The reason for this is that the former syntax tells you where the line starts and where it ends, and name-value pairs then control what the line looks like, i.e. where the line actually passes (moving around objects). Using `sys, points` is like doing `plot(x,y)`, it draws a line between pre-specified points. Using a name-value pair to control the shape is then moot, since you already implicitly provide the shape with the `points`.

---

Doing `[a;b]` creates an array, which is a single variable, hence the error.

Comment: The problem is that `pos_array_out{pos_out}` is a Position from `get_param('System', 'PortConnectivity')` (for example 150 75) and so it returns me `Invalid Simulink port handle` when i do like you say

Comment: I'm using this way of {add_line()`function : `h = add_line(sys,points)`

Comment: It's ok i think i found why thank you for your reply (I can't use parameter with add_line using in/out put position)